# Can't push or pull image after adding a new tag (docker hub)

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm trying to push a new image to docker hub when adding tags.

Initially the push works ok:

```
docker build -t myimage .
docker tag myimage myuser/myrepo:latest
docker push myuser/myrepo:latest
```

but after i add another tag it didn't let me:

```
docker tag myuser/myrepo:latest myuser/myrepo:another
```

i got:

> denied: requested access to the resource is denied

it's the same when i try to pull my repo:

```
docker pull nicoplw/culo2:latest
```

i got:

> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for nicoplw/culo2,
> repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied:
> requested access to the resource is denied

**Note that my repo is in docker hub after i initially pushed it.**

I tried with

```
docker logout
docker login
```

and also with

```
docker login -u username -p password
```

i always get "login successfull"

i tried every stackoverflow and docker forums question but i couldn't make it work. What am i missing here?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens to be that **you can only have 1 private repository**.
If you create a second one it will somehow be created, but if you try to pull or push it will give this pull/push login error.

**Solution:** delete all your repositories if you want to push a new one, or make it public.

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is with your push command

Can you revisit your command or can you share the exert command which you are using

Comment: i edited my post with images and commands, thanks!

Comment: Did you got the solution if not please create a repo in docker hub and then try to push